# How to use program name with out specific path in .cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I usually type following command in command prompt,

```
pageant "C:\Users\test\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
```

It have worked well.

But on the other hands,when I make `test.cmd` file like

```
pageant "C:\Users\test\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
```

And then double click, it didn't work

but`test.cmd` in following script

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pageant.exe" "C:\Users\test\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
```

work well.

What is the different between them ?

I guess The path was recognized by `cmd`.

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Comment: The last example is the correct way to do it, all of the others are shortcuts, which are depenent upon things which are often broken or out of your control. My advice is do not be lazy, use the correct way from your last example. If you're using that location often in your script, you could minimize the additional typing by creating a localized variable, `set "tty=C:\Program Files\PuTTY"`, then you can use `"%tty%\pageant.exe"`. Either way, as you're only typing your script once, there's little need to use unnecessary shortcuts, which as you've already seen can prevent your code from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command doesn't contain an absolute path and isn't an internal command then cmd.exe will find the executable in the current folder and then look in the folders in the `%PATH%` environment variable. It looks like the current folder in your cmd is `C:\Program Files\PuTTY` so `pageant` can be found and execute normally. If you `cd` to a different folder then it won't work unless the folder exists in `%PATH%`